# Postgresql partition pruning and btree_gin indexes not playing ball

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, database-partitioning

The setup can be roughly summarized as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE bird_species AS ENUM('sparrow', 'chicken', 'hawk');

CREATE TABLE bird (
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  species bird_species NOT NULL,
  description TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(species, id)
) PARTITION BY LIST(species);

CREATE TABLE bird_sparrow PARTITION OF bird
FOR VALUES IN ('sparrow');

CREATE TABLE bird_chicken PARTITION OF bird
FOR VALUES IN ('chicken');

CREATE TABLE bird_hawk PARTITION OF bird
FOR VALUES IN ('hawk');
```

description is not null for around 17% of entries.
The table is filled in with a couple million entries.

I want the query

```
SELECT * FROM bird
WHERE
  species = 'sparrow'
  AND description IS NOT NULL
  AND to_tsvector('english', description) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', $1)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

to run at a reasonable speed.
I've attempted creating a btree_gin index:

```
CREATE INDEX bird_species_description_index ON bird USING GIN(species, to_tsvector(description)) WHERE description IS NOT NULL;
```

But the query seems to still fall on an inverted pk index scan followed by a filter.
However, the queries

```
SELECT * FROM bird
WHERE
  species = 'sparrow'
  AND description IS NOT NULL
  AND to_tsvector('english', description) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', $1)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

(does exactly the bitmap index scan on the partial index on the partitioned table you'd expect and is my current hack solution) and

```
SELECT * FROM bird
WHERE
  description IS NOT NULL
  AND to_tsvector('english', description) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', $1)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

(does the correct bitmap index scan on each partition and then joins everything) are both very performant.

I think postgres is falling onto a very queer index plan because it doesn't know what values are actually common in the GIN index, but I don't know how to solve that.

Postgres version: 14.3.

Configuration: default except for 500mb shared buffers, random page cost set to 1.1 and work_mem increased to 2MB.

Comment: I swapped to a column containing the tsvector and this improved things somewhat before it degenerated again. I then raised the LIMIT clause and that improved things, but I imagine that will only last until the database grows again.

Comment: Without seeing the actual plans, we will get no where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably doesn't have anything to do with either partitions or specifically with btree_gin, but is more general problem with the planner.  The planner does not use stats collected on partial expressional indexes to get row estimates.

You have already found that storing the tsvector materialized into the table is one way to fix the problem--no longer an expressional index.  Another way would to drop the WHERE clause from the index definition, so it is no longer partial.  That will make the index somewhat larger as it needs to store ctids for the NULL descriptions, but those compress well, and you never actually need to visit that part of the index with queries of the type you show here.

Also, note that there is no reason to include species into the GIN indexes.  The indexes are already partitioned by that field by virtue of the table being partitioned.  (If some of your partitions do cover multiple species, then it might make sense to include it--but even that is dubious.)

> but I imagine that will only last until the database grows again.

There are all kinds of problems that might possibly show up when the database grows.  I see no reason to think this problem is more likely to reappear than some other problem is to appear (or be recognized) for the first time.  You could set up a test database and stuff it full of plausible but fictional data, and see what happens.

Comment: "Also, note that there is no reason to include species into the GIN indexes. The indexes are already partitioned by that field by virtue of the table being partitioned."
Thanks for telling me, I added them in because I need to for unique indexes on the partition.
Anyhow, removing the NOT NULL condition on the indexes doesn't seem to have done anything.

Comment: Did you manually ANALYZE the table after building the replacement index?

Comment: Yeah, naturally. EDIT: I'll try to configure postgres to increase ANALYZE sample sizes and see if that improves things any.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have done it. ALTER TABLE bird ALTER COLUMN description_tsvector SET STATISTIC 500; I'll mark the question as answered.